# Why people write Flash video players in Flex not in Flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-video

One common hebavior I observed in my slow Internet connection is that most sites on the Web embedding Flash Video, their player is always written in Flex. I can tell by the extremely long loading scroll bar that Flex defaultly provides. From my experience Flash loads faster, Why do people stop writing stuff in Flash anymore?

Are there any fast loading yet rich feature Flash video players>

Comment: If your connection is so slow that the player itself takes an appreciable amount of time to download, you're probably not in the target market for internet video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience is that the components provided by default in the Flex framework are more stable than the ones provided in the Flash IDE. So I'd prefer to use the Flex components simply because it means less time debugging problems in the actual component code. It is however true that players based on the Flex framework tend to be heavier in terms of download size. But since video is bandwidth heavy and people who watch video over the net tend to have good bandwidth these days, I guess the conclusions most developers come to is that the extra download size is an acceptable tradeoff for less time spent in coding boilerplate.

Personally, if the requirements state that the player has to load fast and be light weight then I always roll my own in pure AS3 and just implement exactly as much as is needed. But if there is no such requirement, then I'll use the Flex-components as a base and do customization from there.

As for the second part of your question, sorry can't think of any open source fast loading feature rich flash video players right now.

Answer (score 3):

Flex produces a flash movie (swf), so the end result is still flash.

As for the reason behind it, not everybody has or wants Adobe Flash (Studio) or any of the other timeline based studios.

Flex enables anybody to create a flash based application or widget using XML and the free Flex SDK.

There may also aesthetic reasons such as standardised controls.

Answer (score 1):

Try Flowplayer, JW FLV Media Player and the last contender, but not the least from Adobe - Strobe Media Playback http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html

Answer (score 1):

*From my experience Flash loads faster, Why do people stop writing stuff in Flash anymore?*

When done correctly, there's no difference in how they work - in fact, I'd argue that stuff done in Flex (specifically, using the Flex SDK) give you more freedom to control how loading is done.

But to answer the question, people stopped using Flash just because there's much better stuff out there. Flex Builder, FlashDevelop, FDT - they're all much better tools for any serious coding and debugging. I used to love the IDE, but now I can't fathom how would anyone do anything serious on it, even when using external code editors.

Flash still works when you need vectors, or to create a library with some embeddable assets, but that's pretty much all it's useful for nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I am a flex developer, see flex is somewhere flash, here flex has two frames, preloader stage(first frame) and creationComplete stage(second frame), the same frame concept as flash has, but flash has more than two frames and layer concept is also there

Major differneces comnes in the ease of using the components in flex, in flash, altho flash is one of powerful tools that has changes the web,

but flex gives the freedom, i m using flex, so i know that i can give more time on business login development, rather than concentrating on design aspects,

but it's also true, i have to see the design aspects as well in flex,

so happy flexing